# Is there a way similar check constraint to help me to know if there is a duplicate column

Tags: oracle

> table 1
>   ID - name - main_number - random1 - random2 
>   1* -*aaaa*-blalablabla***- ******* - ***** 
>   2 -*vvvv*-blublubluuu***- ******* - ***** 
>   3 -*aaaa*-blalablabla***- ******* - ******

ID , name and main number are primary key
My problem that I have noticed coulmn name and main number has duplicate values, i dont want to ADD ANY OTHER DUPLICATE VALUES ( I should keep the old duplicat because in my real table there are a lot of duplicated data and its hard to remove them ) 
what I want when I TRY ( BEFORE TO COMMIT) to know that this name I am trying to insert is duplicate. 
I can do that with in a procedure or triger, but i have heard constraint checking is simpler and easier(if there a simpler way then procedure or triger ill be glad to learn it)

> CONSTRAINT check_name
>   CHECK (name = (A_name))

can the constaraint have more then 1 column in such way?

> CONSTRAINT check_name
>   CHECK (name = (A_name) , main_number=( A_number))

can I a write a constaraint in such way?

> CONSTRAINT check_name
>   CHECK (name = (  select case where there is an column has the same value of column name))

So my question : Is there a way simelar to check constraint to help me to know if there is a duplicate column or I have to use a trigger ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your database is Oracle you could also use NOVALIDATE constraints. Meaning: "doesn't matter how the data is, just validate from now on".

```
  create table tb1 
  (field1 number);

  insert into tb1 values (1);
  insert into tb1 values (1);
  insert into tb1 values (1);
  insert into tb1 values (2);
  insert into tb1 values (2);
  commit;

  -- There should be an non-unique index first
  create index idx_t1 on tb1 (field1);

  alter table tb1 add constraint pk_t1 primary key(field1) novalidate;

  -- If you try to insert another 1 or 2 you would get an error
  insert into tb1 values (1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use constraints on many columns.

But in this case constraint is not applicable, because all table rows must satisfy constraints. Use a trigger.

Constraints cannot contain subqueries.

Alternatively use unique index, that will enforce unique constraint

```
create unique index index1 on table1 
     (case when ID <= XXX then null else ID end,
      case when ID <= XXX then null else name end);
```

Replace 'XXX' with your current max(ID).

Comment: No need to cleanup, if use this index, assuming that ID is increasing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to prevent duplicate records as defined by the combination of name and main_number.

Then the way to go is to cleanup your database, and create a unique index:

```
create unique index <index_name> on <table> (name, main_number)
```

This both checks, and speed's it up.

In theory, if you really wanted to keep the old duplicate records, you could get along by using a trigger, but then you will have a hard time trying to get sense out of this data.

*Update*

If you used the trigger, you would end up with two partitions of data in one table - one is checked, the other is not. So all of your queries must pay attention to it. You just delay your problem.

So either clean it up (by deleting or merging) or move the old data in a separate table.

You can use *SQL select ... group by* to find your duplicates, so you can delete/move them in one turn.

Comment: my real table has about 2000 id, and i have abut 200 duplicate column, if I want to clean them , i have to spend days following each id and check if I have to delete or rename it. and why if using the triger it will be hard for me ?

Comment: Yes, that is known as cleaning up after someone else's bad design. Refactoring is required.

Comment: @moudiz I've updated my answer. It won't be funny to base your queries on a shaky ground.

Comment: @Beryllium thanks for the update. I am thinking now with the possibility of cleaning the table . the problem about the cleaning that the id refer to another table , so i must anylise every single id or informations will be lost

Comment: You can do this as well for all records. Actually you are not losing data - it has already been lost :-)

Comment: If your requirement is unique records, then the current data does not comply - you have violations. You never know which of the records really matters. But really - this is a different question.

Comment: @Beryllium ah ok I understand you, this table is foreign to another table , where that(foreign) table contain all the general informations for the ID for this table(this table contain really detailed id), my recuirment to know that i am inserting am duplicate (detailed) information